# Can we read a smoking.mat (dataset) in C-language?

Tags: c, matlab

The reason i want to read it in C is:

i want to create a mnrfit.c file/function in replacement of mnrfit.m

To see "smoking.mat", it is under the Matlab's installation directory:

    C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\help\toolbox\stats\examples"

If it is possible, please tell me how to load that dataset called smoking (i have searched, alot but could not find the way)?

Once, i am able to read/load smoking.mat in C. I will save the dataset in a linked-list (own-made)

Comment: Well, if it has a defined format, you can read it.

Comment: @MOehm , I want a .mat file to be read in a C file-code for that purpose. Is it possible ?

Comment: That would require to parse the Matlab language, which is not trivial. But you really need to be more specific with your question. You ask about "smoking.mat", which is probably a file on your local disk. We can't guess what's in it.

Comment: Its a <150 x 6 dataset>
You would also have it in matlab's directory:
"_____\MATLAB\R2013a\help\toolbox\stats\examples"
<br>You can open it and see it
Can we load that dataset in C, Mr. @MOehm .
Thanx, to consider.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that, because I haven't got Matlab installed. You should probably make that clear in the question.

Comment: What a matfile is depends on the version. Open it in matlab and save it in version 7.3 (check `doc save` for details) . Now you got a gzip compressed HDF5 file. Search how to read HDF5 in C, you will find answers.

Comment: This seems the solution to me @Daniel , thanx. I would have to go through the HDF5 (new-learning :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Library in C/C++:

> mat.h

Here you have all the operations it has. (Including de open/load function)

```
#include <mat.h>

matClose (C and Fortran)    Close MAT-file
matDeleteVariable (C and Fortran)   Delete named mxArray from MAT-file
MATFile (C and Fortran) Type for a MAT-file
matGetDir (C and Fortran)   Get directory of mxArrays in MAT-file
matGetFp (C)    Get file pointer to MAT-file
matGetNextVariable (C and Fortran)  Read next mxArray from MAT-file
matGetNextVariableInfo (C and Fortran)  Load array header information only
matGetVariable (C and Fortran)  Read mxArray from MAT-files
matGetVariableInfo (C and Fortran)  Load array header information only
matOpen (C and Fortran) Open MAT-file
matPutVariable (C and Fortran)  Write mxArrays to MAT-files
matPutVariableAsGlobal (C and Fortran)
```

[This blog contains good info: Matlab C Library Mat File Operations](http://note.sonots.com/Mex/Mat.html#s13b0d34)

Comment: Thanx to give time @ByJokese , but
I want to make it possible in pure C-environment (in a C-compiler).
.....
One possible solution would be to convert .mat to .xls and read it through a C-library libxls(free library(for older excel-versions)) OR LibXL(non-free library)